# Can't import a variable inside a string in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is my code where I  try to link some images from a folder

```
{teamLinks &&
            teamLinks.map(({ title, caption, imgNo }, index) => (
              <div className="col-lg-4">
                <div className="team-member">
                  <img
                    className="mx-auto rounded-circle"
                    src={require(`../assets/img/team/` + { imgNo } + `.jpg`)}
                    alt="logo"
```

and I get this error

```
×

    Error: Cannot find module './[object Object].jpg'
    ▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
    (anonymous function)
    C:/Users/........./Team.jsx:20



 17 | <div className="team-member">
  18 |   <img
  19 |     className="mx-auto rounded-circle"
> 20 |     src={require(`../assets/img/team/` + { imgNo } + `.jpg`)}
     | ^  21 |     alt="logo"
  22 |   />
  23 |   <h4>{title}</h4>
```

need some help please...

Comment: `require(\`../assets/img/team/${imgNo}.jpg\`)`. You can find the documentation for template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: `\`../assets/img/team/\` + { imgNo } + \`.jpg\``  ironic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the two approaches here. Do not end up mixing up both

1. `../assets/img/team/`+imgNo+ `.jpg`
2. `../assets/img/team/${imgNo}.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable 'imgNo' have a object data, it's need to a string data.
You can use
require(`../assets/img/team/${imgNo}.jpg`)

Comment: Well, it might be but likely not. The problem is that user creates a new object `{ imgNo }`

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks